# Showing a UIWebView in a Tabbar with control like TTWebController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

Are there any existing open source `UIWebView` control (with back/forward buttons) that is suitable to be used with a `UITabBarController`?

I have tried to use the `TTWebController`, but the issue is the button controls is at the bottom, so they stack with the  tabbar, the layout is strange then.

I would prefer if any open source web controller has buttons control at the top of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish it is by subclassing `TTWebController`, and repositioning the web controller toolbar in the `loadView` function:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)loadView {
 [super loadView];

 _toobar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.size.width, TTToolbarHeight());
}
```